# Image Upload to database reference original name

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on a codeigniter project. In the image upload config I have it as encrypted to allow unique file names to avoid overwriting and doubling of name and for more security in general.

So on upload it will encrypt the image file name, and store the encrypted name in the database while saving the image in my assets folder. But for some reason it doesn't seem to encrypt the image names at all. Almost like it is completely ignoring the `$config` options and just uploading the image.

Also I have attempted a call back function to avoid blank uploads and again seems that is ignored also and the post are still allowed.

If anyone can lend a tip. Please.

**Controller**

```
//Callback validation
$this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile','Photo','callback_photo_check');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){

      $this->load->view('templates/header');
      $this->load->view('posts/create', $data);
      $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    } else {

       if($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE){

      $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/images/posts';
      $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|jpeg';
      $config['encrypt_name']         = TRUE; //TURN ON
      $config['max_size']             = 0;
      $config['max_width']            = 0;
      $config['max_height']           = 0;

      $this->upload->initialize($config);

      if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){

        $errors = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());

              $this->load->view('templates/header');
              $this->load->view('posts/create', $errors);
              $this->load->view('templates/footer');

      }else {
        $this->post_model->create_post($this->upload->data('full_path'),$this->input->post());
      }

    }

    $this->session->set_flashdata('post_created','Your Post has been submitted');

    redirect('posts');

    }
  }


public function photo_check(){

if(empty($_FILES['userfile'])){
  $this->form_validation->set_message('photo_check', 'need a image');
                       return FALSE;
}

else{
  return TRUE;
}

}
```

**Model**

```
public function create_post($path,$post){

$data = array(

'about'=> $this->input->post('Description'),
'image' => $path,

);

return $this->db->insert('posts',$data);
```

Comment: how did you set config['overwrite']?

Comment: I did not set a value for it since the default boolean is FALSE.

Comment: @PHPNoob please refer my answer below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54738739/image-upload-to-database-reference-original-name/54751719#54751719

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem before, then I decided to give them(files) a unique name, what I did is:
• I assigned an empty variable which will hold the file name/ path data meant to be modified and I named it as `$info_name`.
• Everytime the file name will have a duplicate in the existing location it will add a unique extension such as time(seconds,date, etc).

Here is my sample code:

```
public function new_info($data,$photo){
    extract($data);
    $info_name = "";
    $directory = "C:/xampp/htdocs/Parent folder/child folder/grand child folder/";
    $extension= array("jpeg","jpg","png","gif");
    $file_name=$photo["form_name"]["name"];
    $file_tmp=$photo["form_name"]["tmp_name"];
    $ext=pathinfo($file_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(in_array($ext,$extension)){
        if(!file_exists($directory.$file_name)){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp=$photo["form_name"]["tmp_name"],$directory.$file_name);
            $info_name = $file_name;
        }
        else{
            $filename=basename($file_name,$ext);
            $newFileName=$filename.time().".".$ext;
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp=$photo["form_name"]["tmp_name"],$directory.$newFileName);
            $info_name = $newFileName;
        }
    }

   // then your sql code here for example: 
   $data= array( 'user' => $_SESSION["user_id"],
                 'picture' => $info_name,
                );
    $this->db->insert('sys_post',$data);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To encrypt the uploaded file names, you have to follow below steps.

1) You have to load the Encryption Library.

You can call this library on particular page where there is upload code.

```
// LOAD LIBRARIES
$this->load->library('encryption');
```

OR you can also load it in **autoload.php** file in `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','form_validation','encryption');`

2) Now you are using the Encryption class, you must set an encryption key in **config.php** file.

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'your-own-encryption-key';
```

For more information regarding Encryption => https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html

3) And finally, In your upload code `$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;`.

Hope this will help.